# A Database Error Occurred Duplicate entry 'K0004-AA-BB050'

Tags: sql, codeigniter, sql-update

Help I found error , i want to update my array form

Error Number: 1062

Duplicate entry 'K0004-AA-BB050' for key 'PRIMARY'

UPDATE `md_promo` SET `mdpr_no` = 'K0004', `mdpr_mspd_no` = 'AA-BB050', `mdpr_net` = '1664750.00'

Modal

```
if($data['action'] == 'EDIT'){
            $this->db->where('mspr_no', $data['ms']['mspr_no']);
            $this->db->update('ms_promo', $data['ms']);

            $this->db->where(array('mdpr_no' => $data['md']['mdpr_no']));
            $this->db->delete('md_promo');

            if(!empty($data['md'])){                
                foreach ($data['md'] as $key => $value) {                   
                    $this->db->update('md_promo', $value);
                }
            }
```

View

```
                                        if($action === 'view'){                                                                                  
                                           if(isset($listproduk)){ 
                                                foreach ($listproduk as $value) { ?>
                                                    <tr>                                                      
                                                      <td><input type="text" name="mdpr[mdpr_mspd_no][]" class="form-control srstyle-ta-center mdpr_mspd_no" value="<?php echo $value['mdpr_mspd_no']; ?>" readonly /></td>
                                                      <td><input type="text" class="form-control msph_pl" value="<?php echo $value['msph_pl']; ?>" readonly/></td>
                                                      <td><input type="text" class="form-control msph_hjkk_net" value="<?php echo $value['msph_hjkk_net']; ?>" readonly/></td>
                                                      <td><input type="text" class="form-control msph_hjkj_net" value="<?php echo $value['msph_hjkj_net']; ?>" readonly/></td>
                                                      <td><input type="text" name="mdpr[mdpr_net][]" class="form-control mdpr_net srstyle-ta-right auto-numeric" value="<?php echo $value['mdpr_net']; ?>" readonly/></td>
                                                    </tr><?php
                                                }     

                                             }

                                        } 
                                        ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: post create table script.  It seems you create a PK with mdpr_no and mdpr_mspd_no which already exists.

Comment: the concept is I want to delete data detail and input again, because i dont know code to update data array , thanks dude